# Only the main part of the document has the right encoding

Tags: input-encodings, font-encodings

Been having this problem for a bit and haven't been able to short it out whatever I do.

I'm writing my thesis in LaTeX which is writen in Spanish, therefore it needs to have accentuation in some vocal, e.g: á, é, ú...

Added the following package in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Which actually works fine, the problem that it only works on the main part of the document, so in the appendixes and abstract I get the following type of text:

> Ãžltimas dÃlcadas

Where it should be:

> Últimas décadas

This is driving me crazy, does anyone know how to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The accented A show your input is in UTF-8 so you need to tell latex that `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and then make sure _all_ your input is in that encoding (`fontenc` package is about font encodings so not related to the encoding of your input)

Comment: your text editor should be able to show the encoding your files are in, and save as utf-8

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have tried adding the package you suggest, but when I do after compilling a ton of errors such as this one: "Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ónom (U+14D)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. \LARGE \textsc{***}" appear.

Comment: It is hard to say without an example but it would appear that some of your files are in UTF-8 and some are in latin1 (iso-8959-1) it is in fact possible to get latex to switch encodings mid document but it is tricky to get cross references to always use the right encoding and _much_ easier to save all your files in latin1 and use `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` or save all your files in utf-8 and use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (you need to load inputenc with some option if you have any characters such as `á` otherwise you need to enter them using ascii commands `\'{a}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, managed to solve it as you said I had different coding on some of the pages so when compilling it was giving problems on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following packages need to be added in the preamble of the document:

`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

It is very important that all the pages of the document has UTF-8 encoding if not errors will happen when compiling.